# Try-with-resources close order

Tags: java, jdbc, java-io, try-with-resources, autocloseable

I am looking at examples of try-with-resources in Java and I understand the following one:

```
try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pwd);
     Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
     ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);) {
  ...
}
```

So, the order of closing is:

```
rs.close();
stmt.close();
conn.close();
```

which is perfect because a connection has a statement and a statement has a result set.

However, in the following examples, the order of close I think it is the reverse of the expected:

**Example 1:**

```
try (FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
     BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr)) {
  ...
}
```

The order of closing is:

```
br.close();
fr.close();
```

**Example 2:**

```
try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("testSer.ser");
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fs);) {
    ...
}
```

The order of closing is:

```
oos.close();
fos.close();
```

Are these examples correct? I think the close in those examples should be different because:

1. In the example 1 a BufferedReader has a FileReader.
2. In the example 2 an ObjectOutputStream has a FileOutputStream.

Comment: The `br` depends on the `fr` (just like `rs` depends on `stmt` depends on `conn`), so `br` should be closed first (and the `br` will close the `fr` itself as well). Your expectation is just wrong; you may want to explain why you think `fr` (and `fos`) should be closed first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I wasn't right when I said "a connection has a statement and a statement has a result set". Maybe it's the opposite "a result set has a statement and a statement has a connection" or at least "a result set was created by a statement and a statement was created by a connection".

So I think:

```
try (Parent parent = new Parent();
     Child child = parent.createChild();) {
    ...
}
```

Is equivalent to:

```
try (Parent parent = new Parent();
     Child child = new Child(parent);) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 13):

The ordering is the same: it's always the reverse of the order in which resources are specified. From [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.3):

> Resources are closed in the reverse order from that in which they were initialized.

However, if the later-specified resources themselves invoke the `close()` method of the earlier-specified resources (as is the case with `BufferedReader` and `ObjectOutputStream`), it may look like they are not happening in the expected order (and that `close()` will be invoked multiple times).